# HighStocks Fixed Xaxis 30 minutes interval

Tags: highcharts

I have been creating a Highstock chart and I am facing problem in fixing `xAxis` interval in date/time formatter code here according to live stock data on 30 minutes interval.

Here is the code of my chart:

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            timezoneOffset: 4 * 60
        }
    });
    var dataObject = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'area',
            width: '1280',
            height: '640'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                hour: '<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                day: '%Y<br/>%b-%d',
                week: '%Y<br/>%b-%d',
                month: '%Y-%b',
                year: '%Y'
            },
         tickPositions:['09:00:000','12:00:00','15:00:00','18:00:00']      
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            min: minRange,
            max: maxRange,
            tickInterval: 0.5,
            title: {
                text: 'Last',
                margin: 40
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
           fillColor : {
            linearGradient : {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0.8,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 0
            },
            stops : [
                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
        },
          data: [[1440161106000,112.65],[1440161931000,112.65],[1440162841000,112.65],[1440163745000,112.65],[1440164584000,111.41],[1440164704000,111.11],[1440165543000,111.51],[1440166443000,110.96],[1440167345000,110.66],[1440168183000,109.29],[1440168300000,109.5],[1440169144000,109.17],[1440170038000,108.29],[1440170945000,108.92],[1440171784000,108.48],[1440171904000,108.61],[1440172743000,108.81],[1440173640000,108.6],[1440174544000,107.72],[1440175385000,108.03],[1440175503000,107.99],[1440176338000,108],[1440177245000,108.24],[1440178143000,108.4],[1440178983000,108.28],[1440179104000,108.21],[1440179915000,108.2],[1440180844000,108.3],[1440181743000,108.06],[1440182585000,107.71],[1440182705000,107.51],[1440183543000,107.5],[1440184444000,106.53],[1440185345000,106.08],[1440186184000,106.61]]            }]
    };
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(dataObject),function(chart){

        $('#container').bind("mousewheel",function(event,delta){

            var x = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120;
            console.log(x);

            if (delta > 0) {
                var min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min,
                    max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;

                chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes((min + 12 * 3600 * 1000),(max - 12 * 3600 * 1000));
            } else {
                var min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min,
                    max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;

                chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes((min - 12 * 3600 * 1000),(max + 12 * 3600 * 1000));
            }
        });

    };
```

JSFiddle : [jsfiddle.net/zubairsultan/cvnzkv0s/5](http://jsfiddle.net/zubairsultan/cvnzkv0s/5)

Comment: Maybe we can help you if you supply some code or JSFiddle ...

Comment: ok im giving my code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zubairsultan/cvnzkv0s/5/

Comment: Ok, and what do you want exactly ? What is the problem with your chart ?

Comment: Xaxis datetime is changing dynamically i want it to be static fixed interval e.g, fixed on hourly base

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/dsf6c7b4p/

Comment: Tickpositions should be defines as timestamp (time in miliseconds), not as strings. Use a Date.UTC() to return correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix `minTickInterval` to 3600000 so your `xAxis` will be "hourly based":

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                hour: '<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                day: '%Y<br/>%b-%d',
                week: '%Y<br/>%b-%d',
                month: '%Y-%b',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            minTickInterval: 3600000
},
```

See your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/cvnzkv0s/9/

Is that what you want ?